# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug' in Android

Tags: android, phonegap-build, cordova-plugin-proguard

Error in android studio when apk build.

```
Error:-Error:Execution failed for task
 ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. 
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
 java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
 com/google/android/gms/dynamic/LifecycleDelegate.class
```

My bundle config file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile files('libs/cordova-2.9.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: Your project's dependency and your external jar file one of the class conflicted. So you'r getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to disable Instant Run:

[image]

Comment: same error:-Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/dynamic/LifecycleDelegate.class